# Hide Action bar In a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, fragment, hide

I'd like to hide the Action Bar of my Fragment.
I searched on Google for 1-2h. But I didn't find any proper anwser...
So if you could help me that would be nice.

Comment: Your Fragment doesn't have a Title Bar. Maybe search for changing fullscreen mode.

Comment: Yes my Fragment has a Title Bar or an Action Bar, I don't really know how it's called... And I don't know how to remove it.

Comment: If it's an Action Bar it's part of the Window decoration and therefore part of the Activity the Fragment is attached to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `getActivity().getActionBar().hide();`

Comment: Yeah I already tried this but the app crashes when it starts.

Answer (score 0):

It is called `ActionBar` You can hide Action Bar using `getSupportActionBar().hide();`

Comment: Yeah I already tried this but the app crashes when it starts.

Comment: @NufMeister Are you using fragment with main activity or using as a view pager? Put up come code for us to understand. If it is a crash, is the crash because of this statement?